# Can I change the background of a LinearLayout from a ListView row in the ViewBinder?

Tags: android, background, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I have a `ListView` with some elements and I want to change the background of the row depending on their type in the database. What I got is a `SimpleCursorAdapter` instance and it's function `adapter.setViewBinder(...)`. But it seems, that I can't access the `LinearLayout` of a row. Here's the code:

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.day, c, new String[] { "name_con", "start", "end",
                    "type", "prof", "room" }, new int[] { R.id.subjectName,
                    R.id.subjectStart, R.id.subjectEnd, R.id.subjectType,
                    R.id.subjectProf, R.id.subjectRoom });

    adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.subjectName:
                final String colNameName = cursor.getString(1);
                ((TextView) view).setText(colNameName);

                return true;
            case R.id.subjectStart:
                final int colNameStart = cursor.getInt(2);

                Date dStart = new Date(colNameStart * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdfStart = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
                String startString = sdfStart.format(dStart);

                ((TextView) view).setText(startString);

                return true;
            case R.id.subjectEnd:
                final int colNameEnd = cursor.getInt(3);

                Date dEnd = new Date(colNameEnd * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdfEnd = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
                String EndString = sdfEnd.format(dEnd);

                ((TextView) view).setText(EndString);

                return true;
            case R.id.subjectType:
                final int colNameType = cursor.getInt(4);

                switch(colNameType){
                case 0:
                    ((TextView) view).setText(R.string.practice);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ((TextView) view).setText(R.string.course);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ((TextView) view).setText(R.string.practica);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ((TextView) view).setText(R.string.seminar);
                }

                return true;
            case R.id.subjectProf:
                final String colNameProf = cursor.getString(5);
                ((TextView) view).setText(colNameProf);

                return true;
            case R.id.subjectRoom:
                final String colNameRoom = cursor.getString(6);
                ((TextView) view).setText(colNameRoom);

                return true;
            case R.id.dayCell:
                ((LinearLayout)view).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.subjectName:
                final String colNameName = cursor.getString(1);
                ((TextView) view).setText(colNameName);
                ((LinearLayout)view.getParent()).setBackgroundResource(<resource id>);
                return true;
```

EDIT: for efficiency, you'll probably only want to do it in one of the `ViewBinder` passes, and you'd need to be sure its a LinearLayout that's created in `R.layout.day` or you'll end up with a ClassCast exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the setBackgroundColor(int color), setBackgroundResource(int) or setBackgroundResource(int resid) to change the background of your view.

BR,
Christoffer

Answer (score 0):

Override [bindView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#bindView%28android.view.View,%20android.content.Context,%20android.database.Cursor%29) in your `CursorAdapter`

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```